# STM32 timer PWM input capture and reset in slave mode (SPL)

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, timer, stm32f10x

Could someone explain how PWM capture mode employs the Timer's Master-Slave mechanism?
The [example](https://github.com/g4lvanix/STM32F1-workarea/blob/master/Project/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Examples/TIM/PWM_Input/main.c#L76) sets up input capture on Channel 2 but does not explain how IC1 is configured implicitly to capture the falling edge.

I am especially interested in these three SPL functions:

```
 /* Select the TIM3 Input Trigger: TI2FP2 */
  TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM3, TIM_TS_TI2FP2);

  /* Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode */
  TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM3, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

  /* Enable the Master/Slave Mode */
  TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM3, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
```

implemented in stm32f10x_tim.c. They all write to TIMx->SMCR.

According the diagram from UM0008 rev 14 ([rev 16](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf)) ...

[image: ST UM0008 rev. 14 Figure 100. General-purpose timer block diagram]

... TI2FP2 is not even connected to IC1, that would be TI2FP1.
So I can understand that these commands configure the reset. But what causes IC1 to capture?

Comment: Note that in UM0008 section "15.3.6 PWM input mode" suggests that both capture units be configured, which the example does not do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just caught my eye that the PWM_Input example uses `TIM_PWMIConfig()` instead of `TIM_ICInit()` as the InputCapture example does. This is where the missing part is happening: it also configures the other input capture channel.
Note that the automatic reset apparently only works for channels 1&2, not 3&4, as their signal is not connected to the "Slave mode controller".